# magento 2 : How to use curl?

Tags: magento2, curl, curl-request

I am trying to to create the curl request but it is not working. It is giving the error

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Custom\Rma\Helper\Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl' not found
```

**Code**

```
$header = array(
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "content-type: application/json"
            );
        $request = json_encode($sfData);
        $url = "url_here";
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request
        );
        $curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
        $curl->setOptions($options); 
        $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $url, '1.0');
        $response = $curl->read();
        $err = $curl->error();
        if ($err) {
            return false;
        } else {                 
            return true;
        }
        $curl->close();
```

As i want to change my code according to the ECG so i have converted the PHP curl functions to above code. And this code is not working.

Comment: The code you have used is for Magento 1.

Comment: @sv3n this code is used in magento 2

Comment: I see,  but the code you use is for Magento 1 ... so you'll see an error.

Comment: @sv3n any idea how to use curl in magento 2.

Comment: you can read this post of [how to use curl in magento 2](https://www.mageants.com/blog/how-to-use-curl-in-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 5):

> initialize variable

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
 */
protected $_curl;
```

> initialize construct parameter

```
public function __construct(
    PsrLogger $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
)
{
    $this->_curl = $curl;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}
```

> in your function

```
try{
        $url = "https://url.com";
        //if the method is get
        $this->_curl->get($url);
        //if the method is post
        $this->_curl->post($url, $params);
        //response will contain the output in form of JSON string
        $response = $this->_curl->getBody();
       // $responseArr = $response->__toArray();
        $em  =  array();
        $this->_logger->addDebug($response,$em);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->critical('Error Curl', ['exception' => $e]);
    }
```

check this its working for me. check debug.log to verify the response

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can i get the curl_error. Is there another function? I want to return the false if curl_error

Answer (score 1):

You can call curl by injecting `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl` class.

For looking into how to call various methods of curl you can look into file `vendor\magento\framework\HTTP\Client\Curl.php`.

Comment: You can see some usage at: `app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php`. Apparently they use `CurlFactory`.