# Magento 2 send data to an API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, dashboard

I would like to have data from Magento 2 dashboard shown in some visualization software and have found documentation from the other site about their API, but I can't find any information from Magento to send data somewhere else. If possible, the data from Magento should be sent with a POST request to the other company's API.

Can anyone help med find documentation on how to send the data from Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here
[magento 2 : How to use curl?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215954/magento-2-how-to-use-curl)
and [Magento 2 REST API usage with examples](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170921/magento-2-rest-api-usage-with-examples)

for more details read this devdoc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/gs-curl.html

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't provide a centralize way to make api REST call to external services.
I worked with multiple customers and it seems like developers always use their own REST implementation, using differents libraries on same project like Guzzle, Curl, Zend...

That's why I recommand you to use this module to industialize your REST API call through Guzzle library: https://github.com/zepgram/module-rest